# Does _msize return the argument given to malloc() or the memory block size?

Tags: c, windows, malloc

Suppose I have the following code

```
void* p = malloc(1);
size_t size = _msize(p);
```

Does _msize give me the argument which I gave to malloc and I need to give to free(), or the number of writable bytes that I can use?

Because I have tested for many sizes, and it always gives the argument which I gave to malloc, but I heard functions like malloc() do not give you exactly what you asked for, they usually find the size with closest multiple of 8 or nearest alignment.

Comment: "The _msize function returns the size, in bytes, of the memory block allocated by a call to calloc, malloc, or realloc." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/msize?view=msvc-170

Comment: I would not realy on the MS documentation :). Can you explain what you need this function for?

Comment: @0___________ truly wondering, nothing interesting. Because I saw somewhere (lost it) in python developer website that Python uses this and the linux version of it to optimize the python mem allocator (?)

Comment: @DanielA.White So are you saying every time I malloc(x) I don't get even x + 1 bytes? never? because this is what my tests showed. But yeah I have seen this reference.

Comment: @Null **linux** ???? It is MS "invention". IMO totally useless unless the allocator may return less memory than requested and you need to behave acordingly

Comment: @0___________ malloc_usable_size (?) I use windows so im not sure

Comment: @Null I would not use excess bytes as it is rather bad practice :) Rather add some `#if`s and allocate accordingly to the implementation if the actual size really matters. Micro optimizations like this are the main source of the hard to debug errors.

Comment: @0___________ not that I am trying to, I was basically trying to understand what was happening there.

Comment: Depends on what you designate as the "block". You get a pointer to enough usable memory for the size you requested. Sure, the allocator may store some metadata adjacent to your memory, however the metadata isn't yours but the allocators, so why should it include it in *your* block size?

Answer (score 1):

It returns `>=` the size you allocated with `malloc`. In other words, it tells you how many bytes you are allowed to use without calling `realloc` for more memory.

If you need to know the exact size then you need to keep track of that yourself.

Comment: But it does not answer his question why it is always equal the requested size.

Comment: The Microsoft C run time has existed for a long time in many versions and his happens to return the same number but I would not rely on that. Win32 does the same https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120316-00/?p=8083

Comment: So what does this answer answer?

Comment: The documentation for _msize says malloc block and the documentation for malloc says the block may be larger.